# XSD validation optional string and only 4 numbers

Tags: xsd

I need a validation in this XSD.
FD is optional.
If you fill in FD it should have only 4 numbers (not 2 numbers or 5 numbers)

```
                    <xs:element name="FD" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>FD-code optional only 4 numbers</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:length value="4" fixed="true"/>
                          <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
```

Currently, the xsd rejects an empty value.

Question:
How do I get it to accept an empty value and if it does contain something filled that it only contains four digits?

So:
Empty is good
1 digit is wrong
2 digits is Wrong
3 digits is wrong
4 digits is Correct
5 digits is wrong
letters is wrong

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: As Pavel said, what is your question?  That piece of XSD seems to do exactly what you are wanting.  In what circumstances is it failing?  Note you could simplify it by using "[0-9]{4}" instead

Comment: Sorry you are right, Currently, the xsd rejects an empty value.

Question:
How do I get it to accept an empty value and if it does contain something filled that it only contains four digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are using length instead of maxLength. Also, the pattern that you use requires 4 numbers, not 0-4 numbers.

Try this instead:

```
<xs:element name="FD" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>FD-code optional only 4 numbers</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="4"/>
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{4})?"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: When I send no value in the FD element <FD></FD>    I got this error: "The 'FD' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Pattern constraint failed."

Comment: The problem is in the pattern, the pattern expects 4 numbers, not 0-4 numbers.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: We are almost there:
Empty is going well
If I enter three digits he accepts them, this is not allowed. Four digits must be filled in (not one or two or three digits)
So:
Empty = good
1 digit = wrong
2 digits = Wrong
3 digits = wrong
4 digits = Correct
5 digits = Faulty
letters = wrong

Comment: I misread the original question, try the updated answer. But really at this point it is just about getting the right regular expression for the pattern you want